# Global variables in matlab

Tags: matlab

I define a variable d like this

```
global d
d = 4;
```

However, when I later call this variable in a function, it is not recognized `Undefined function or variable 'd'.`

Isn't this [the way global variables are declared](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)?

Comment: Seriously consider whether you need to use global variables. In allmost all cases it is considered better practice to simply give the variable back as output of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function that calls this global variable, you need to add the following line to the function before using it:

```
global d;
```

---

It is necessary declare a variable as global within a function body in order to access it. For example,

```
function testglobal()
clearvars -global
global d
f ()
d == 1

function f()
d = 1;
```

does not set the value of the global variable x to 1. In order to change the value of the global variable x, you must also declare it to be global within the function body, like this

```
function testglobal() 
clearvars -global
global d
f()
d == 1

function f()
global d;
d = 1;
```

Check out [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Global-Variables.html) for more info.

Comment: I have updated the example a bit, it should now be possible to copy it into a file directly.